# Selenium how to get hidden value inside html which is not showing in the html element

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I working on one site where I found an input field value like

[image]

Here value **Hotel rupdia** is coming automatically from Database. But when I inspect the element I have found not set any value. And I am not sure how can read this text from here using selenium. As value not stored in any attribute or value

Here is the Html

```
<fieldset class="form-group position-relative outline-none" id="__BVID__458"><div tabindex="-1" role="group" class="bv-no-focus-ring"><input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Property name" autocomplete="new-password" class="form-control is-valid" inputmode="text" id="__BVID__459"><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><div class="invalid-tooltip">  </div><!----><!----><!----></div></fieldset>
```

Can anyone face this type of issue? And help me to find out the solution?

Comment: Use this xpath`//div[@class='bv-no-focus-ring']//input[@name='name']` as `String val =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='bv-no-focus-ring']//input[@name='name']")).getAttribute('value'); and print this `val`, Also remember to put some sleep before using this code and let me know if that prints something or not.

Comment: I have given that as an answer in case if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this xpath

```
//div[@class='bv-no-focus-ring']//input[@name='name']
```

as

```
String val = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='bv-no-focus-ring']//input[@name='name']")).getAttribute("value");
```

and print this val, Also remember to put some sleep before using this code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead `.getText().` try applying `.getAttribute("value")` on that web element